# How particular windows form set as start up project in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to set particular windows form as start up project in visual studio 2013. And I completed multiple form designing but I can't link one form to another.How to execute one by one form.

[image: Project settings]

How do I change setting in project properties?

Comment: Only classes with a static Main() method show up in that combobox.  Consider modifying your existing Program class, edit Main() the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly you have several forms and you are trying to set a specific one as the very first?

you should set a new instance of your DesiredForm in your Program.cs

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new DesiredForm()); // <---
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you now its working after changing the Application.Run(new DesiredForm()) from program.cs